# UI keyboard not appearing when UI textfield tapped after model to a different view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, first-responder, resignfirstresponder

Ok. So I have been testing out a simple application on xcode to become familiar with the platform, but I've come across an interesting situation. Using storyboard, I've dragged two view controllers that are connected by buttons by segues. They both have a uitextfield dragged on them that respond on click when they are the initial view. However, when I move to another viewcontroller from the buttoned segue, the keyboards no longer automatically popup. Is this a problem with apple's uitextfield? (ps. there is no code to this as I thought this would simply be automatic responding)

Comment: Do you mean that the keyboard doesn't show up if you tap the text field, or just that it doesn't come up on its own when the view loads?

Comment: It doesn't show up if I tap the text field. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to see if the view hierarchy has become messed up.  You can easily see this in the 'document outline.'

[image: Document Outline]

If you don't see this pane, look on the left, bottom side of the storyboard and click the small arrow pointing to the left.

What do you see here?  Is the Text Field an immediate child of the View or of something else?  If it's an immediate child, do you see other children of View listed here that you don't recognize?

Comment: I had a scroll view in-between them. When I removed it, it worked fine again. Thanks again!